# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in (\:directory) on line 436

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm getting this error in Wordpress and I don't know what it's asking. Here is the code starting on line 436.

```
if (count($this->keys) && $this->action == 'add') {
                
                // Extract the last key
                $last = $this->keys[count($this->keys) - 1];

                // Are we trying to add stuff?
                if ($last == $this->add_key) {
                    $this->data = $this->set_data($this->default, $this->keys);             
                }

            }
```

Its in a plug in called 'more fields. Its updated.
I don't know what to try. PHP isn't my forte.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more context, source code.

Comment: I'd say find a new plugin. If it's [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/more-fields/), there has been no updates in 12 years, and was tested up to WP 3.2.1, and is closed an no longer available for download. Considering the error, it's not compatible with newer versions of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is a really old plug in, and that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, Generators, Objects (with public properties) and Iterators are implementing the [Countable Interface](https://php.net/manual/en/class.countable).

If it is not one of those types you will get this error.

To fix this error you can check if it is **countable**.

```
if (is_countable($this->keys) && count($this->keys) && $this->action == 'add')
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, ChatGPT pointed out that

```
$this->keys
```

Might not be an array in some contexts. I would have never guessed that, but PHP isn't my forte. ChatGPT suggested checking to see if it was an array before implementing.

The fix:

```
if (is_array($this->keys) && count($this->keys) && $this->action == 'add') {
// Extract the last key
$last = $this->keys[count($this->keys) - 1];

// Are we trying to add stuff?
if ($last == $this->add_key) {
    $this->data = $this->set_data($this->default, $this->keys);             
}
```

}

Looks to be working and implemented well with the old plug in.
If there is anything anyone else would like to point out, I'm all ears and willing to learn. Thank you.

Comment: That is wrong. Not only arrays are countable.